# d3-force - why does this graph pulse?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

The snipped below is intended to mimic retrieving a data set (which may change) regularly from a web service and merging that data into a d3 force-directed graph.  I copy the location and velocity of each node across from the old simulation nodes into the new node list, but still, every time the simulation is restarted, the nodes which aren't hard up against the borders of the SVG pulse slightly towards the centre of the diagram.

How can I avoid this effect?

```js
function nodes() {
  let nodes = {};
  for (let ii = 0; ii <= 10; ii++) {
    nodes[`${ii}`] = {
      id: ii
    };
  }
  return nodes;
}

function links(nodes) {
  let links = {};
  for (var a in Object.keys(nodes)) {
    for (var b in Object.keys(nodes)) {
      links[`${nodes[a].id}-${nodes[b].id}`] = {
        id: `${nodes[a].id}-${nodes[b].id}`,
        source: `${nodes[a].id}`,
        target: `${nodes[b].id}`
      };
    }
  }
  return links;
}

let display = d3.selectAll("div");
var displaySize = display.node().getBoundingClientRect();
let r = 3;
let svg = display.append("svg");
let g = svg.append("g");

let node = g.selectAll("circle");
let link = g.selectAll("line");

function ticked() {
  node.attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  link.attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
    .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
    .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
    .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
}

let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(displaySize.width / 2, displaySize.height / 2).strength(0.01))
  .force("link", d3.forceLink()
    .id(d => d.id)
    .distance(5).strength(0.01))
  .force("limit", d3.forceLimit()
    .x0(r).y0(r).x1(displaySize.width - r).y1(displaySize.height - r))
  .alphaMin(0.5)
  .on("tick", ticked)
  .on("end", update)
  .stop();

let localNodes = {};
let localLinks = {};

function update() {
  simulation.alpha(1).restart();
  let nextNodes = nodes();
  let nextLinks = links(nextNodes);
  for (var ii in nextNodes) {
    if (ii in localNodes) {
      nextNodes[ii].vx = localNodes[ii].vx;
      nextNodes[ii].vy = localNodes[ii].vy;
      nextNodes[ii].x = localNodes[ii].x;
      nextNodes[ii].y = localNodes[ii].y;
    }
  }
  for (var ii in nextLinks) {
    nextLinks[ii].target = nextNodes[nextLinks[ii].target];
    nextLinks[ii].source = nextNodes[nextLinks[ii].source];
  }
  
  localNodes = nextNodes;
  localLinks = nextLinks;

  node = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(Object.values(localNodes), d => d.id)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", r);

  link = g.selectAll("line")
    .data(Object.values(localLinks), d => d.id)
    .join("line");

  simulation.nodes(Object.values(localNodes))
    .force("link").links(Object.values(localLinks));
}

update();
simulation.alpha(1).restart();
```

```css
circle {
  stroke: #000;
  fill: #000;
}

line {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #000;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-force-limit@1.1.7/dist/d3-force-limit.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Reducing the simulation.alpha() value seems to have reduced the constant pulsing. It still has movement, but is less than what you had originally. Is this what you wanted?

```js
function nodes() {
  let nodes = {};
  for (let ii = 0; ii <= 10; ii++) {
    nodes[`${ii}`] = {
      id: ii
    };
  }
  return nodes;
}

function links(nodes) {
  let links = {};
  for (var a in Object.keys(nodes)) {
    for (var b in Object.keys(nodes)) {
      links[`${nodes[a].id}-${nodes[b].id}`] = {
        id: `${nodes[a].id}-${nodes[b].id}`,
        source: `${nodes[a].id}`,
        target: `${nodes[b].id}`
      };
    }
  }
  return links;
}

let display = d3.selectAll("div");
var displaySize = display.node().getBoundingClientRect();
let r = 3;
let svg = display.append("svg");
let g = svg.append("g");

let node = g.selectAll("circle");
let link = g.selectAll("line");

function ticked() {
  node.attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  link.attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
    .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
    .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
    .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
}

let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(displaySize.width / 2, displaySize.height / 2).strength(0.01))
  .force("link", d3.forceLink()
    .id(d => d.id)
    .distance(5).strength(0.01))
  .force("limit", d3.forceLimit()
    .x0(r).y0(r).x1(displaySize.width - r).y1(displaySize.height - r))
  .alphaMin(0.5)
  .on("tick", ticked)
  .on("end", update)
  .stop();

let localNodes = {};
let localLinks = {};

function update() {
  simulation.alpha(0.5).restart();
  let nextNodes = nodes();
  let nextLinks = links(nextNodes);
  for (var ii in nextNodes) {
    if (ii in localNodes) {
      nextNodes[ii].vx = localNodes[ii].vx;
      nextNodes[ii].vy = localNodes[ii].vy;
      nextNodes[ii].x = localNodes[ii].x;
      nextNodes[ii].y = localNodes[ii].y;
    }
  }
  for (var ii in nextLinks) {
    nextLinks[ii].target = nextNodes[nextLinks[ii].target];
    nextLinks[ii].source = nextNodes[nextLinks[ii].source];
  }
  
  localNodes = nextNodes;
  localLinks = nextLinks;

  node = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(Object.values(localNodes), d => d.id)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", r);

  link = g.selectAll("line")
    .data(Object.values(localLinks), d => d.id)
    .join("line");

  simulation.nodes(Object.values(localNodes))
    .force("link").links(Object.values(localLinks));
    
}

update();
simulation.alpha(0.5).restart();
```

```css
circle {
  stroke: #000;
  fill: #000;
}

line {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #000;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-force-limit@1.1.7/dist/d3-force-limit.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```

Reducing it more would reduce the kinetic energy of the graph even more. You can adjust it until you find a value that you like.

```js
function nodes() {
  let nodes = {};
  for (let ii = 0; ii <= 10; ii++) {
    nodes[`${ii}`] = {
      id: ii
    };
  }
  return nodes;
}

function links(nodes) {
  let links = {};
  for (var a in Object.keys(nodes)) {
    for (var b in Object.keys(nodes)) {
      links[`${nodes[a].id}-${nodes[b].id}`] = {
        id: `${nodes[a].id}-${nodes[b].id}`,
        source: `${nodes[a].id}`,
        target: `${nodes[b].id}`
      };
    }
  }
  return links;
}

let display = d3.selectAll("div");
var displaySize = display.node().getBoundingClientRect();
let r = 3;
let svg = display.append("svg");
let g = svg.append("g");

let node = g.selectAll("circle");
let link = g.selectAll("line");

function ticked() {
  node.attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  link.attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
    .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
    .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
    .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);
}

let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(displaySize.width / 2, displaySize.height / 2).strength(0.01))
  .force("link", d3.forceLink()
    .id(d => d.id)
    .distance(5).strength(0.01))
  .force("limit", d3.forceLimit()
    .x0(r).y0(r).x1(displaySize.width - r).y1(displaySize.height - r))
  .alphaMin(0.5)
  .on("tick", ticked)
  .on("end", update)
  .stop();

let localNodes = {};
let localLinks = {};

function update() {
  simulation.alpha(0.1).restart();
  let nextNodes = nodes();
  let nextLinks = links(nextNodes);
  for (var ii in nextNodes) {
    if (ii in localNodes) {
      nextNodes[ii].vx = localNodes[ii].vx;
      nextNodes[ii].vy = localNodes[ii].vy;
      nextNodes[ii].x = localNodes[ii].x;
      nextNodes[ii].y = localNodes[ii].y;
    }
  }
  for (var ii in nextLinks) {
    nextLinks[ii].target = nextNodes[nextLinks[ii].target];
    nextLinks[ii].source = nextNodes[nextLinks[ii].source];
  }
  
  localNodes = nextNodes;
  localLinks = nextLinks;

  node = g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(Object.values(localNodes), d => d.id)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", r);

  link = g.selectAll("line")
    .data(Object.values(localLinks), d => d.id)
    .join("line");

  simulation.nodes(Object.values(localNodes))
    .force("link").links(Object.values(localLinks));
    
}

update();
simulation.alpha(0.1).restart();
```

```css
circle {
  stroke: #000;
  fill: #000;
}

line {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #000;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-force-limit@1.1.7/dist/d3-force-limit.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
```